# Create a separate variable for each element of a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of data frames, which was produced from reading in 25 .csv files at once.  I would like to unlist the data frames to begin a spatial analysis.  That is, I would like to have individual data frames for each element of the list.

I have tried `unlist()`, but it does not produce the result I want.  I have also tried an approach with `lapply()`, but it produces an error.  Here's what I've tried:

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 4:6

l <- lapply(1:2, function(x){data.frame(x, y)})

lapply(1:length(l), function(i){paste('df', i, sep = '') <- data.frame(l[[i]])})
```

The problem seems to be in assigning the data frame to the pasted name.  Wrapping it with `as.character()` did not help.

This does work:

```
"df1" <- data.frame(l[[1]])
```

It seems the problem is somewhere in the output of my `paste()` function, but the output has `str()` 'chr'.  Any ideas how I can make my approach work?  Is there a cleaner way to unlist my data frames?

Comment: `?assign`, if you feel you must do this, or `?attach`. Keeping them in a list is generally a much better idea though.

Comment: Off-topic, but why does assigning to `"df1"` work? I wouldn't have expected it to.

Comment: @Marius - from `?"<-"` where it states `x <- value` and `x: a variable name (possibly quoted)` So this means `"<-"(blah,1:10)` and `"<-"("blah",1:10)` give the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
list2env(setNames(l,paste0("df",seq_along(l))), envir = parent.frame())
```

Though I would heed @baptiste 's advice before it is too late and avoid doing this.
Why? Because in two days time you'll find yourself trapped using `get()` and `paste` and messy loops to try to apply a function to all of your datasets at once. If you keep them in a list you can just do `lapply(l,functionname)`.

Comment: Nice answer.  Those are all new functions to me.  I guess my motivation behind taking it out of a list is I'm new to lists, so it seemed easier.  But there's no time like the present, so I'll just try to roll with it as a list and learn a thing or two.  Thanks.